# Is the addition in modules finite $?$

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

If  $M$  is  a  module  over  a  commutative  ring $R$, then $$m_1+m_2 \in M$$ for  all  $m_1,m_2 \in M$ .

Now from   this  I  can  say  for  $n\lt \infty$ , and  $m_i\in M$  we  have $$m_1+m_2+.....+m_n \in M$$

But  can  we  write  this  for  $n=\infty$ $?$

When  $R$  is  a  commutative  ring  and  $B$  is  any  set , the  $R^B$  implies  the  set  of  all  functions  from $B$  to  $R$ .  If  we   consider  only  the  functions  with  *finite  support* then   then  they  make  into  an  $R$-module with  the  *basis*  elements  being $\delta_b$  s.t.  $\delta_b(x)=\delta_{xb}$ .  In  this  case ,  if  we  add  finite  number  of $\delta_b$'s  then the  obtained  function  is  still of  *finite support*   but  if  we  add  infinite number  that  does  not  satisfy  the  above. I  know  any  element  is  finite linear  combination  of  the  basis  elements but the  basis  elements  are  elements  of  the  module . When  we  add  *infinite*  elements  of  the  module  how does  that  go  outside  the  module $?$

Answer (score 1):

Infinite linear combinations are not defined unless you have some kind of metric or other topology on the module. Usually infinite sums are defined as the *limit* of the finite sums; however, limits only make sense in topological or metric spaces.

So infinite sums do not make sense in your example.

Comment: ok.  so  not  defined .  that  means  I  need  not  bother  about  that .  thanks .